# Is this a Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve this, and no such luck.  Is the statement yrue?

> If $A$ is an $n\times n$ non-singular matrix, then $A^{-1}+{\left(A^T\right)}^{-1}$ is a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that if $A$ is invertible then

$${\left(A^T\right)}^{-1}={\left(A^{-1}\right)}^T$$

Comment: How do I prove or show this? Not sure how to go about it.

Comment: We have that, by definition, $A^T\, {\left(A^T\right)}^{-1} = {\left(A^T\right)}^{-1}\, A^T = I$. Now, write

$$A^T {\left(A^{-1}\right)}^T = {\left(A^{-1}\, A\right)}^T$$

Can you conclude? Remember that the inverse is unique.

Comment: OK, so that makes symmetric?  Thanks

Comment: No -- that's a hint. You should **use** the hint to show that it is symmetric.

Comment: Its been a very long time that I did Linear Algebra, so if $(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$. So really, $A^T(A^{-1})^T=(A^{-1}A)^T=I$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, because $I^T=I$. Still, you should use the hint to show that $A^{-1}+{\left(A^T\right)}^{-1}$ is symmetric.

Comment: So, How is that?

Comment: You should be able to take it from here. I'm not about to do all of your homework for you -- and I've done quite a lot of it already.